# nmap search for specific IP range

Tags: ip, nmap

How can I search with `nmap` in a specific range of IPs?

Like only IPs in `10.{1-99}.{1-99}.1`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like:

```
nmap 10.1-99.1-99.1
```

other options than can be used:

```
nmap 10.*.1.11
nmap 10.1.1.0/24
```

You can specify a range but exclude specific hosts:

```
nmap 10.1.1.1-80 --exclude 10.1.1.5
```

From `10.1.1.1` to `10.1.1.80` except `10.1.1.5`.

```
nmap 10.1.1.1,2,3
```

or even:

```
nmap 10.1,2,3.1.1,2,3
```

Which scans these hosts: `10.1.1.1`, `10.1.1.2`, `10.1.1.3`, `10.2.1.1`, `10.2.1.2`, etc.